# How can I return False if a character in a string appears three times in a row

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have asked this question before, and although the response from the kind StackOverflow users were right, it kinda fails to answer my question, or it's kinda complicated for a beginner like me, so I'm gonna ask again :).

So here is a code which checks whether a string fits certain criteria or not....

```
def passwordlength(password: str):
    upper = digit = special = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" :
            upper = True
        elif char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        elif char in "$#@%!":
            special = True
    return upper and digit and special

def password(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password):
        if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
            return False
    else:     
        return True
```

So this part works fine. no problem with my initial code. However, I'm trying to edit my code so that if **a number, character or letter appears 3 times in a row.. for example, AAA or ccc or 111 or ###, the output would be false**

Here is my attempt at it, which didn't work at all...

```
def passwordlength(password: str):
    upper = digit = special = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" :
            upper = True
        elif char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        elif char in "$#@%!":
            special = True
    return upper and digit and special

def password(password: str):
    if passwordlength(password):
        if not (6 < len(password) < 12):
            return False
        for char in password:
            if password.count(char) > 3:
                return False
        return True
    return False
```

What should I change in my code to make sure this works??

Please use the simplest form of coding possible since I'm a beginner and I would like to learn along as I do programming :). Also pls don't use `import` or `collections.iter` because I haven't learnt that yet... I'm learning python online and I haven't learnt that far yet.. Thank you :)

Comment: I love `re` myself. I always use `re` when working with strings.

Comment: am I missing something here perhaps? I dont see `re` mentioned in the question anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial implementation would be:

```
def check_repeating_chars(password):
    for i in range(2, len(password)):
        if password[i] == password[i-1] == password[i-2]:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 8):

You could check this:

```
any(char * 3 in password
    for char in password)
```

Or with your style:

```
        for char in password:
            if char * 3 in password:
                return False
```

Comment: Might as well do `for char in set(password)` so you can avoid multiple checks for a duplicate character.

Comment: @Reti43 Yeah, but I'd say passwords are short and such password validity checks are rare, so it doesn't need to be fast. So I prefer it simple.

Comment: Sometimes it is even preferable to choose an intentionally slow algorithm for checking/verifying passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will take a string as input and will return `true` if any character appears three times in a row, otherwise it will return `false`:

```
def does_char_appear_three_times_in_a_row(input_string):
    last_char = ''
    count = 0
    for c in input_string:
        if c == last_char:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
        if count == 3:
            return True
        last_char = c
    return False
```

Comment: It's better to use a simple meaningful method/function name instead of sentenses

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Says who? The function name makes perfect sense here, both from a self-documenting and educational point of view.

Comment: Agreed with Selcuk, **simple is not always better**. For example, what does a list named `L` say about anything? I actually like this function name, as it's clear if not concise, but I prefer clear over concise if it comes down to it.

Comment: This is actually one of the aphorisms in [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): _"Explicit is better than implicit."_

Comment: I know the zen of python and that's why I love python. And here I mentioned simple **meaningful** which covers both aspects. BTW 'If there's a shorter, but yet descriptive way to name the function, then the function name is too long.' If you want a full description that's whats the comments do (# or """ triple quotes is for) # personal_preference

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Fair enough. "How explicit" is always opinion based. That being said, a blanket "do not use sentences" statement is not always correct.

Comment: @Selcuk totally agreed

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following idea:

```
qtt = 0
last_char = None
for char in password:
  if char == last_char:
    qtt += 1
  else:
    qtt = 0

  if qtt == 2:
    return False
  last_char = char
```

You walk through each char in the string, then compare it with the last char, if they are the same you count, if not, you have to start to count again, so pass 0 to `qtt`. If the `qtt` equals to 2, you found 2 last_chars equal to chars, it gives to you 3 sequences of the same char. At last, you change the last_char to the actual char, so in the next time it will be the last_char and the for will give you a new one. I hope a was sufficient didactic.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as @ErikMcKelvey's answer?

Comment: Yes, it is, but When I answered he hadn't answered yet. Probably we answered almost at the same time

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not work the way you want because `password.count(char)` counts **all** occurrences of `char`. A possible way to do what you want to do is this:

```
def check_char(password):
   for n in range(0, (len(password)-2)):
      if (password[n] == password[n+1]) and (password[n] == password[n+2]):
         return False
   return True
```

But I will recommend using Regex, instead.

Comment: Note that in Python you can write `if password[n] == password[n+1] == password[n+2]:`.

Comment: I believe such answer already exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70075101/2055998

Comment: Right! I just saw another answer here that did that. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: This is an example where simple is not better. In this case, the function name is extremely vague.